# Setting a global minHeight and/or minWidth

Tags: android

I've a drawable XML file, in which I set global parameters for my butons, using code like

```
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
     <corners android:radius="4dip" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#555555" />
    <solid android:color="#dddddd"/>
    <size android:height="20dip"/>
    </shape>
```

That's OK, but of course, as the default minHeight of button seems to be 48dp, the height of 20 does nothing.
I know I can use

```
     android:minHeight="0dp"
     android:minWidth="0dp"
```

but I want to set these values as "global" for all my buttons. Searching in Android Doc (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape), it seems minHeight and minWidth are not part of Shape Drawable.
So where can I set minHeight and minWidth in a global way?
Thanks

Comment: you can create a custom button style xml file and then add the minheight attribute to that. Then you just set that style to all your buttons. See this website http://blog.danlew.net/2014/11/19/styles-on-android/ (ctrl+f minWidth)

Answer (score 3):

You want to define a custom button style and apply it to your theme.

For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/SmallerButtonStyle</item>

</style>

<style name="SmallerButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:minHeight">20dp</item>
</style>
```

This will change every `Button` in your application to default to a minimum height of 20dp.

If you don't want *every* button to be that small, you can also apply this style to individual `<button>` elements as usual.

For more, see the [Styles and Themes documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define your dimension on res/values/dimens and add

```
<dimen name="name_dimen">20dp</dimen>
```

and them add to your element(s)

```
<Button
    android:layout_height="@dimen/new_dimen"
    ......../>
```